# PWM on Raspberry Pi 2 and Windows 10 Core IoT RTM

Tags: pwm, windows-iot

Now that windows 10 Core IoT - final RTM version is available. Are there any ways to program a Windows Universal App to use PWM hardware connected to the GPIO?

I need this for controlling the color of a LED strip. Previously only software / timer based solutions were possible but they do not work well. Documentation is still in Preview.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Hardware PWM and ADC are not supported right now on RPi2 (Windows IoT). You need some extra circuitry which can generate PWM or record ADC on demand. I have done some work to manipulate PWM and ADC which are linked at the end of the answer.

**How you can achieve PWM & ADC on RPi2 + Windows IoT?**
RPi2 will be connected to a gateway device via I2C/SPI Bus. A gateway device is nothing more than a microcontroller like Arduino. We need to program gateway to respond RPi2. Gateway device will act as I2C/SPI slave. Whenever RPi2 requests to write specific PWM pin, Gateway will generate PWM for that pin on demand.

**I have done some work on PWM & ADC which might help you:**
PWM Servo Control (RPi2 + Windows IoT):
https://www.hackster.io/AnuragVasanwala/windows-10-iot-core-ultrasonic-distance-mapper-d94d63

PWM Motor Speed Control & Retrieve ADC (RPi2 + Windows IoT):
https://www.hackster.io/AnuragVasanwala/windows-10-iot-core-hydroflyer-f83190

Comment: If promoting your own work you must fully disclose that.

Comment: Sure sir. But I didn't promoting myself instead I just mentioned what is the another possible way which might help others.

Comment: Is that not your name in the link above?

Comment: Aslo posting the same answer to multiple questions is considered gaming the system.

Comment: Yes, its the article I written to understand the issue which I can't explain here as it might not be feasible.

Answer (score 1):

I'm fairly sure the answer is no and will always be no.

See this official [Windows blog](https://blogs.windows.com/buildingapps/2015/08/10/hello-windows-10-iot-core/)

- Improved support for Python and Node.js, including a new Express Node.js project template
- GPIO performance on the Raspberry Pi 2 has improved by 8X to 10X
- Analog-to-digital converter (ADC) and pulse-width modulation (PWM)
  are now supported via breakout boards and ICs
- New Universal Windows Platform (UWP) APIs give apps easy control over
  system management features like time zone and network connections

Comment: I saw this info, however, why do you thing it will always be no? :/ Also, no one wire chips, like temperature sensor... ?

Comment: @hkusulja Perhaps I am being unduly negative.  I know that implementing PWM on the hardware pins is fairly trivial.  I suppose my reasoning is if it was going to be done it would have been done by now.  As for 1-wire there is little evidence that Windows IoT can deal with the microsecond timings needed.

Comment: so where is a example for this 1 wire chips ?

Comment: @hkusulja I do not use IoT so may be mistaken but I am not aware of any 1-wire devices working on the Pi with IoT.

Comment: DS18B20 Temperature Sensor works fine on RPi debian version

Comment: @hkusulja I know, I have used DS18B20s myself on the Pi.  Linux has a 1-wire driver, WIndows IoT does not.

Comment: This is the correct answer.. there will be no PWN on IoT because Windows10IoT is NOT real time OS and cant handle microsecond timings like some *nix can.

Comment: While this might have once been correct, it is absolutely not correct now.  I have a working PWM sample in Windows IoT.  It might not be a realtime OS, but it works well enough to fade LED's and do variable speed motors.

Comment: @LeeRichardson The question asked about using the Pi's PWM hardware (the two PWM channels built into the SoC).  Is your sample using the hardware?

Comment: @joan I think so.  I'm pretty sure that's what the "[1]" is for in await PwmController.GetControllersAsync(LightningPwmProvider.GetPwmProvider()))[1].  See my answer for a more complete code sample.

Answer (score 1):

Check out [Microsoft.IoT.Lightning.Providers](https://ms-iot.github.io/content/en-US/win10/LightningProviders.htm).  To implement pull down "Microsoft.IoT.Lightning" via Nuget (the source is at [Microsoft.IoT.Lightning.Providers](https://github.com/ms-iot/BusProviders/tree/develop/Microsoft.IoT.Lightning.Providers/Providers) project).  From there follow the usage example in [PwmConsumer](https://github.com/ms-iot/BusProviders/tree/develop/Microsoft.IoT.Lightning.Providers/PwmConsumer).  It worked well enough to variable speed control a motor.

Here's a code sample that sets the duty cycle to 25%:

```
LowLevelDevicesController.DefaultProvider = LightningProvider.GetAggregateProvider();
pwmController = (await PwmController.GetControllersAsync(LightningPwmProvider.GetPwmProvider()))[1];
motorPin = pwmController.OpenPin(5);
pwmController.SetDesiredFrequency(50);
motorPin.SetActiveDutyCyclePercentage(.25);
motorPin.Start();
```

I also put together a blog post on [PWM in Windows IoT](http://blog.infernored.com/how-to-fade-an-led-with-pwm-in-windows-iot) with in-depth step by step details about how to do this.

Comment: Can you share a code with this please? Thank you

Comment: Added a code sample as requested.  Setting this up was a bit tricky, so I'm actually working on a blog post, which I'll also reference when done.